# How to show multiple forms simultaneously

Tags: c#, winforms

I know this may have been answered, but I just can't find a suitable answer. Any idea how to show more than one Windows Form?

```
static void Main()
{
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
     Application.Run(new Main());
     Application.Run(new MenuModule());
}
```

By declaring two `Application.Run`, the the Windows Form will show after I exit the first.

Comment: What is the relationship between these two forms? When your application should be closed? I mean what form has the responsability to keep your application open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use that overload of `Application.Run` it will block until the form you passed has closed.

You could try:

```
new Main().Show();
new MenuModule().Show();
Application.Run();
```

This will run until you call `Application.Exit` even if both forms have been closed. So a better option might be:

```
new MenuModule().Show();
Application.Run( new Main() );
```

Which will cause the application to exit after the `Main` form has closed, regardless of the status of the `MenuModule` form.

As an option you could also have the `Main` form show the second one, that'll work too.

Answer (score -1):

you can create an object in 'Main' class (form) contractor.

```
public main(){
     .
     .
     .
     new MenuModule().show();
     .
     .
     .
}
```